# How to access M-values in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, linear-referencing

I am working with Linear Reference Systems and I know is very easy to get M coordinate (M-value) from a shapefile in ArcGIS. But, how to get the M-value in QGis?

If you have doubts about my issue, please look how ArcGIS works with M-value: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003900000006000000

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but I'm wondering if you ever figured this out. I had a very similar, if not the same, question and my solution ended up being me writing a python script to do this inside of QGIS. My answer is here http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/226117/56050

Answer (score 1):

There is a stable QGIS 2.0 plugin called LRS (Linear reference system builder and editor). You can install it from the QGIS Plugins Repository.

There are information [here](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/lrs/) and in the [documentation](http://blazek.github.io/lrs/release/help.0.3.0/index.html).

Comment: I use LRS plugin, but my issue is different. I want to get M-value before the Linear Reference System. Pay attention, the last link on GIS.se is not from LRS plugin (is another plugin, not compatible ot QGis 2.0, created by Faunalia).