# Error when Add GeoJSON protocol layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, vector, qgis-2.18, qgis-2.14

I tried to add these GeoJSON files to QGIS (2.18.9 & 2.14.15) with Add a vector layer by Protocol, GeoJSON with GUI OR Python Console:

- https://raw.github.com/geobabbler/geodata/master/geojson/leonardtown_bldgs.geojson
- https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.geojson

[image: Add a GeoJSON layer by QGIS protocol]

But I get always this error: `Data source not valid`

[image: Error when adding layer]

What's going wrong with QGIS?

When I add the file downloaded, it's working.

Comment: Are you trying to add the GeoJSON layers via the interface or the Python Console? For QGIS 2.18.2, I can confirm it works when adding them through the interface as you have shown in your image,

Comment: By the interface AND by python console. Same error :/

Comment: Works for me too. Are you behind a proxy? Can you download the files and add them locally from disk?

Comment: Yes, from the disk it works but i would like to use the protocol way to get alvays the updated version. It doesn't work for me in 2.14 and 2.18. Maybe i m behind a proxy.....checking on http://www.proxyornot.com..... I m not behind a proxy.

Comment: Works for me in QGIS 2.18.3

Comment: This may be similar to a problem I ran into here https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/226406/56050

Comment: You could try wrapping the URL in a OGR VRT file. Anything relevant in the protocols (the balloon in the lower right edge)?

Comment: @nmtoken under linux? windows?

Comment: Judging on the post time on Windows

Comment: OK, strange, it works for me under Linux but not in Windows. But for you it works under WIndows. Where did you download your Windows Version? Me from osgeo4w. Maybe it could be a build problem with missing library?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After some troubleshooting, found out that it will work if I change our url from https to http

Comment: Ok, it works for the second link. But if the service is only https like the first one, it's not a complete solution? But thank you

Comment: Maybe, we should add the certificate to qgis?

Answer (score 1):

On [NextGIS QGIS](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/) under Mac OS X the both URLs work fine. This version of NextGIS QGIS based on QGIS 2.14 LTS.

[image]